# C# Asp.net filtering on a datagridview with 3 textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagridview

I want to filter a DataGridView with 3 textbox, I get the values correctly but it works just with the first column ('Surname') and it doesn't filter when I type a 'Name' or a 'Phone':

```
protected void btnRic_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSurname.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtName.Text))
            {
                isPhoneNumber = false;
                if (txtCell.Value.Length >= 8)
                {
                    string phoneNumber = txtCell.Value;
                    isPhoneNumber = true;
                }
                DataTable dt = ViewState["dTableGrid"] as DataTable;
                DataView dv = dt.DefaultView;
                if (!isPhoneNumber)
                {
                    dv.RowFilter = string.Format("Surname LIKE '{0}%' OR Surname LIKE '% {0}%' OR Name LIKE ' {1}%' OR Name LIKE '% {1}%'", txtSurname.Text, txtName.Text);
                }
                else
                {
                    dv.RowFilter = string.Format("Surname LIKE ' {0}%' OR Surname LIKE '% {0}%' OR Name LIKE ' {1}%' OR Name LIKE '% {1}%' OR Phone LIKE ' {2}%' OR Phone LIKE '% {2}%'" , txtSurname.Text, txtName.Text, txtCell.Value);
                }
                Grid.DataSource = dv.ToTable();
                Grid.DataBind();
```

Comment: I need 'a%' OR '%a%' and yes it works properly

Comment: Yes, it works only when I search a 'Surname'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (!isPhoneNumber)
{
  dv.RowFilter = string.Format("Surname LIKE '{0}%' OR Surname LIKE '%{0}%' OR Name LIKE '{1}%' OR Name LIKE '%{1}%'", txtSurname.Text, txtName.Text);
 }
 else
 {
   dv.RowFilter = string.Format("Surname LIKE '{0}%' OR Surname LIKE '%{0}%' OR Name LIKE '{1}%' OR Name LIKE '%{1}%' OR Phone LIKE '{2}%' OR Phone LIKE '%{2}%'" , txtSurname.Text, txtName.Text, txtCell.Value);
  }
```

**Update** 
Check whether this blank spaces between `'% {0}%'` is not causing problem.

Comment: dv.RowFilter = string.Format("Surname LIKE '{0}%' OR Surname LIKE '% {0}%'", txtSurname.Text);
       dv.RowFilter = string.Format("Name LIKE ' {0}%' OR Name LIKE '% {0}%'", txtName.Text);

Comment: It still works for the surname but when I filter 'Name' the result is an empty DataView :(

Comment: Goddamnit m8, you're right the problem was the blank space ç_ç, many thanks!